# add multiple extra plugins on a toolbar of ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to add multiple plugins(which i have created) on a toolbar of ckeditor. I have written below code in config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbar_Full =  [
        ['Styles', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],
        ['Link', 'Unlink'], ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'SelectAll'], '/', ['timestamp', '-', 'linkbutton']
    ];
    config.extraPlugins = 'linkbutton, timestamp';
};
```

and i have two different custom plugins. but another plugin is not accepted. How to add another plugin on a one toolbar?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You are just right except of the space after the comma so your definition regarding http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.extraPlugins should be:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'linkbutton,timestamp';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another custom plugin like this also:

```
extraPlugins: 'linkbutton,timestamp,justify'
```